# Is there any possibility to migrate vm from Redhat Virtualization to Hyper-V?

Tags: virtualization, redhat, hyper-v

I would like to migrate VM's from Redhat Virtualization (RHV 4.2) to Hyper-V environment.What are the possibilities over there? Any opensource or third party tools??

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of v2v converters. In most cases only vdisk image will be converted and you need to create new Hyper-V VM with same CPU/RAM/Network resources with attached converted image.

Here is overview of some  V2V converters – https://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/

I used starwind v2v.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't use any special hypervisor-dependent software inside the VM, I'd simply try bringing clones of all the disk images into a Hyper-V supported disk format, recreate the VM characteristics there (e.g. CPU model/architecture, # cores, RAM, network devices, MAC addresses,) and start that new VM there. Of course, if in the same LAN you should bring down the original VM when trying to bring up this clone. The guest OS itself should not even realize that it's running in a different hypervisor now.

I've moved VMs from VirtualBox to KVM using this process in the past. Have also virtualized old actual physical production servers into VirtualBox VMs in the past a few times with this exact same process.

Comment: I think it is the easiest route. There are a variety of tools, which can do it. I assume your vdisks are qcow2, which can be converted by: 
https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter